# How to set up a specific iOS Version in the Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I am getting a report from a user that my app is crashing in iOS 10.3.3. How would I go about running this in simulator to try and recreate the crash? If I try to download it under Xcode -> Preferences -> Components, it only has previous versions, not the new betas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. I have Xcode 8.3.3, 8.3.2 and 9 on my machine and none of them make any 10.3 version other than 10.3.1 available. 10.3.3 is (as I imagine you are aware) available to developers as a configuration profile or a restore image but these can only be used with a development device. And Apple do recommend using a development device so I guess that's your answer, really.

Comment: Fair, thanks for the reply. Will keep this open just in case someone has a workaround, but will mark as closed in a week or so. Actually, they do allow testing iOS 11 with the xcode beta, so perhaps they also allow 10.3.3 test as an emulator somewhere?